# TradingView creating alert to a strategy

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I'm new at this. I look forward to your experience.
I found a new strategy for myself, but I don't understand how to add an "alertcondition" for it so that I can create alerts.
Also I can't change "strategy" to "study" and I don't understand why.
I hope for your help.

This is the code of the strategy in which I am unable to create alerts:

```
//@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10)
maxIdLossPcnt = input.float(1, "Max Intraday Loss(%)")
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(maxIdLossPcnt, strategy.percent_of_equity)
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long)
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short)
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

This is the strategy code in which I managed to create alerts:

```
//@version=4
study(title="UT Bot Study", overlay = true)
//CREDITS to HPotter for the orginal code. The guy trying to sell this as his own is a scammer lol. 

// Inputs
a = input(1,     title = "Key Vaule. 'This changes the sensitivity'")
c = input(10,    title = "ATR Period")
h = input(false, title = "Signals from Heikin Ashi Candles")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BACKTESTING RANGE
 
// From Date Inputs
fromDay = input(defval = 1, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromMonth = input(defval = 7, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromYear = input(defval = 2022, title = "From Year", minval = 1970)
 
// To Date Inputs
toDay = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
toMonth = input(defval = 1, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
toYear = input(defval = 2100, title = "To Year", minval = 1970)
 
// Calculate start/end date and time condition
startDate = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)
finishDate = timestamp(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 00, 00)
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate
 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


xATR  = atr(c)
nLoss = a * xATR

src = h ? security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close, lookahead = false) : close

xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
xATRTrailingStop := iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss),
   iff(src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss), 
   iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss)))
 
pos = 0   
pos :=  iff(src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
   iff(src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
   
xcolor = pos == -1 ? color.red: pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue 

ema   = ema(src,1)
above = crossover(ema, xATRTrailingStop)
below = crossover(xATRTrailingStop, ema)

buy  = src > xATRTrailingStop and above 
sell = src < xATRTrailingStop and below

barbuy  = src > xATRTrailingStop 
barsell = src < xATRTrailingStop 

plotshape(buy,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= color.red,   textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)

barcolor(barbuy  ? color.green : na)
barcolor(barsell ? color.red   : na)

// strategy.entry("long",   true, when = buy  and time_cond)
// strategy.entry("short", false, when = sell and time_cond)

alertcondition(buy, "UT long open", "message")
alertcondition(sell, "UT long close", "message")

if(buy)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "buy@\n"+tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_labelup)

if(sell)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "sell@\n"+tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_labeldown)
```

Comment: What are you trying to say? is it a doubt or an issue? can you be more specific

Comment: " I found a new strategy for myself, but I don't understand how to add an "alertcondition" for it so that I can create alerts." - this is not neccesary to add anything into strategy code. Just add a strategy on chart and call Create Alert Dlg for it. More info https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000481368

Comment: Alert is created for the strategy. I need to create alerts for opening and closing trades like for "study". It's not the same

Comment: You will recieve the alerts when new order from the strategy will be filled (opening and closing trades). If you want to have different alert messages for opening and closing orders this is possible too (using alert placeholders or using `alert_message` parameter for `strategy.entry` and `strategy.exit` and `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this:

```
//@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10)
maxIdLossPcnt = input.float(1, "Max Intraday Loss(%)")
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(maxIdLossPcnt, strategy.percent_of_equity, alert_message = "closed by intraday loss (" + str.tostring(maxIdLossPcnt) + "%)")
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long, alert_message = "entry long")
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short, alert_message = "entry short")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

[image: example]